# Codeigniter URL structure

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I would like to implement the following url structure over the codeigniter

```
http://client.xyz.com/division/controller/controller_fuction
```

Will you please let me know how can i change the route file to meet my requirement. Thanks.

Comment -

I would like to setup client wise sepearate database and 'division' may be like division1, division2. Depend on the url setting and session would be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

set in the config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then apply htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|img|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

this way you can do like http://client.xyz.com/division/controller/controller_fuction

OR 
 you can use Routing

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own route class, CI lets us to replace or extend it's core functionality. Just create e.g

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router
{
   //so on ..
}
```

Then save it in `application/core` folder, then CI will using your Class instead of default.

look ? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create MY_Controller which will extend CI_Controller.
Every other controller will extend MY_Controller.
Then in MY_Controller you can use this in constructor.

```
$controller = $this->uri->segment(1);
$controller_function = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Here you can define $devisions or get it from config.

```
$division1  =   array('controller1','controller2','controller3');
$division2  =   array('controller4','controller5','controller6');
$division3  =   array('controller7','controller8','controller9');


if(in_array($controller,$division1)){
    //do blah blah
}else if(in_array($controller,$division2)){
    //do other blah blah
}else{
    //do last and final blah blah
}
```